# PHP Output Multiple Files In Multiple Directories

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, glob, scandir

I have a main directory called PDFS that has 5 sub directories representing years(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015).  In each "year directory" are 11 pdfs.  I need to access the PDFS directory and get all "year directories", and then get all pdfs in each "year directory" to display on a page.  So for example the pdfs in the 2011 "year directory" will be listed under a 2011 heading.  Same with 2012, 2013 etc.  I've tried many different things.  I can output the "year directories" using scandir().  I can output the files in a single "year directory" using a foreach loop and glob().  I can't for the life of me figure out how to output each "year directory's" files other than doing multiple foreach loops using glob() on each "year directory".  There's gotta be a more dynamic way to set this up.  Any suggestions?  I feel like I would need some kind of foreach inside of a foreach?  Here's what I'm working with:

```
//set main directory
$dir = 'PDFS';

//gets sub directories of PDFS directory
$directories = scandir($dir);

//removes the first to indexes in the directories array that are just dots
unset($directories[0]);
unset($directories[1]);

//outputs an array of the sub directories from scandir() starting at index 2
print_r($directories);

//initialize $i variable for loop
$i=0;

//if I manually set the $dir variable to "PDFS/2011/*" this will output links
//to each pdf inside the 2011 year directory
    foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
        $i++;
        echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a><br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, this piece of code should do the trick:

```
//set main directory
$mainDir = 'PDFS';

//gets sub directories of PDFS directory
$subDirectories = scandir($mainDir);

//removes the first two indexes in the directories array that are just dots
unset($subDirectories[0]);
unset($subDirectories[1]);

// first loop through all sub directories ...
foreach($subDirectories as $subDirectory) {
    echo '<h1>'.$subDirectory.'</h1>';
    // ... and then loop through all files in each sub directory
    foreach(glob($mainDir.'/'.$subDirectory.'/*') as $file) {
        echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a><br />";
    }
}
```

I changed some of the var names for better understanding.

A few things:

- There is no need for the counting var `i` as you use a foreach.
- If you set a string together manually, then try to generate it step-by-step and just compare the generated with the manual one until it fits. (You connect two strings with a dot `.`)
- You can configure the glob function, so that it only finds certain file types (`*.pdf`).

Comment: Oh man I was close wasn't I?  HA!  Thanks so much for your help, one last thing.  The final loop for the 2015 output is listing the 10th and 11th months first.  So like:

PDFS/2015/10-2015.pdf, PDFS/2015/11-2015.pdf, PDFS/2015/2- 2015.pdf, PDFS/2015/3-2015.pdf, etc...I can sort of understand why but all the rest are outputting in the correct order.  Anything I can do to reorder the last pass through?

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding the order: In a 'perfect world' they should/would be named 01-2015.pdf, 02-2015.pdf, etc., then the order should be correct. Otherwise you could influence the order manually, for example by in this case checking each string in the second loop regarding the file name length or the pattern. Oh and by the way: If your problem is solved by an answer, you should consider marking the appropriate answer as 'solved'. ;)

Comment: Oh right, sorry this was my first post on stack overflow.  I'll rename them with zeros in front.  Either way the links will need to be renamed as months as I output them...which I will save for a new post if I can't figure it out.  Thanks again.